# How can I convert a list of .png to a list of pdf in makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to loop over a list of .png files and convert them to a corresponding pdf file:

```
PICLIST = $(sort $(wildcard pic??.png))

all:
for i in $(PICLIST) ; do \
    convert -resize 80% $$i $(wildcard pic??.pdf) ; \
    done
```

but i got some errors as follow:

```
for i in pic01.png pic02.png pic03.png ; do \
    convert -resize 80% $i  ; \
    done
convert: no images defined `pic01.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3145.
```

Comment: This question is useless.  It's like saying "I wanted to start my car today but I couldn't"; how is anyone supposed to respond to that?  How did you "use" it?  What errors did you get?

Comment: please check it again

Comment: What happens if you try `convert -resize 80% pic01.png` by hand?

Comment: I wanna convert 1000 pictures to pdf files. That's why I want to use a sort of loop or list.

Comment: Beta is asking you to try the command yourself, on one file, to see what the result will be.  If you don't know what the right command is to run yourself from the shell prompt, then you don't know how to get make to run the command for you.

Comment: @MadScientist: Thanks for your explanation. I knew what Beta asked and I tried it before but my question was not for one file and I need to convert many files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use `$(wildcard ...)` inside the recipe.  Make will always expand all variables inside the recipe before it starts the shell that will run the recipe, and before the for-loop starts there are no `.pdf` files, so the wildcard function expands to nothing.  This gives you an illegal command line for `convert`.

Also I don't see how you can have 1000 pictures if they're numbered `00` to `99` (your wildcard only matches two characters--maybe they use letters as well?)

However, why are you even using a makefile here?  You just have one target, that runs one command (a for loop).  Why don't you just write a shell script instead of a makefile?

If you want to do it the "make way" where each time a `.png` file is modified that, and only that, image is converted to a `.pdf`, then you have to do something like this:

```
CONVERTFLAGS := -resize 80%

PICLIST := $(wildcard pic??.png)
PDFLIST := $(PICLIST:%.png=%.pdf)

all: $(PDFLIST)

%.pdf : %.png
        convert $(CONVERTFLAGS) $< $@
```

Comment: Great @MadScientist! This is what I wanted :)
Thanks...
You are right I couldn't have 1000 pics, I had to use wildcard for three characters!

Comment: If this answers your question please click the checkmark next to it to accept, so it's marked as an answered question.